# How to resolve www issue in base url from ngnix.conf file

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl-certificate, no-www

My ngnix.conf file is as shown below..
I am trying to hit **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** in browser, then the url is getting hit is like **https://www.www.example.com//**
and this gives me en error.
Also the url **https://example.com** is not working.

```
    server {
    #server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com www.example.com example.com;
    server_tokens off;
    # Redirects http to https
    location / {
        #return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        #non www to www
        rewrite ^(.*) https://www.$host$request_uri$1 permanent;
    }
```

The error is like -

*Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from example.com (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). Learn moreNET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID*

Note - My certificate is not expired yet..

Answer (score 1):

I have got an answer.

I have generated certificate previously like -

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual \
  --preferred-challenges=dns \
  --email asdf@example.com \
  --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory \
  --agree-tos \
  --manual-public-ip-logging-ok \
  -d *.example.com \
```

Now I have changed my certificate generation procedure like as follows -

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual \
  --preferred-challenges=dns \
  --email asdf@example.com \
  --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory \
  --agree-tos \
  --manual-public-ip-logging-ok \
  -d *.example.com \
  -d example.com
```

This resolved my problem.